# how to echo literal variable value with zsh

Tags: zsh

I have a simple shell function to convert a *nix style path to Windows style (I happen to be using Windows Subsystem for Linux).

```
# convert "/mnt/c/Users/josh" to "C:\Users\josh"
function winpath(){
  enteredPath=$1

  newPath="${enteredPath/\/mnt\/c/C:}" # replace /mount/c/ with C:
  newPath="${newPath//\//\\}"          # replace / with \

  echo $newPath
}
```

The desired behavior is:

```
$ winpath /mnt/c/Users/josh
C:\Users\josh
```

This works correctly in bash, but in zsh, `echo` seems to do some extra interpolation of the `$newPath` value.  It behaves like this:

```
$ winpath /mnt/c/Users/josh
C:sers\josh
```

What character sequence is `echo` interpolating and why is it remove the \U?  Most importantly, how do I return the literal value?

I've tried digging through the zsh documentation, but it's a jungle.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding a quadruple-escaped backslash in `newPath="${enteredPath/\/mnt\/c/C:\\\\\\\\}"` works around it, but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: `echo` is notorious for behaving differently from shell to shell. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` processes certain escape sequences that `bash` does not by default. `\U` introduces 4-byte Unicode codepoint, but since the following 8 characters are not a valid hexadecimal number, no character is substituted.

I would recommend using `printf`, as its behavior is much more predictable from shell to shell.

```
printf '%s\n' "$newPath"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the internal command `echo`, instead of the external one. If you would write

```
command echo $newPath
```

you would get the expected output. `command` forces zsh to look up the command word according to the current `PATH`, ignoring internal commands, aliases or functions of the same name.